# How to fix display:inline-block on IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

How to fix `display:inline-block;` on IE6 ?

My html Page http://www.faressoft.org/tutorialTools/slideShow/

**can I get the same result in other way ?**

[image]

Comment: You've saved your CSS files with an UTF-8 BOM and you're serving them without a charset in the content type header. I'd suggest to fix it as well. I'm not sure how IE6 would react on the presence of the incorrectly encoded UTF-8 BOM prior to the first CSS rule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to re-specify `display:inline;` on block level elements in your IE style sheets.

HTML:

```
<div class="ImageSlideShow">blah</div>
```

REGULAR CSS:

```
.ImageSlideShow { display:inline-block; }
```

IE CSS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.ImageSlideShow { display:inline; zoom:1; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

See: http://work.arounds.org/using-inline-block-ie7-and-ie6/

**BONUS:**

You should also specify `display:inline;` for `.ImageSlideShow .ImageNum {}` to alleviate another IE bug.

Comment: I know this is super old but for others coming here (like myself) you don't need a conditional comment for this. All you need is .ImageSlideShow{display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;} and it will work just fine. IE6&7 are the only browsers that recognize *display so all others will ignore it.

Comment: It's arguably more elegant to use condcoms, though, but for succinctness and if you don't care about perfect validation go ahead.

Comment: That depends if you believe adding extra markup in your structure is more succinct and semantic compared to adding two more attributes in your CSS (where design elements are supposed to live.) But, you're right, you could argue either way depending on your position on that front.

Answer (score 5):

```
* html p { display: inline; zoom: 1; }
```

Answer (score 4):

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

In IE6 you can set display:inline-bock only to real inline elements like span or a.

Comment: Could anyone explain why my answer is voted down? Can't see any missinformation here. IE 6/7 accepts display:inline-block value only on elements with a natural display: inline. To verify here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html