# Chrome recently introduced a css bug?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

It seems that some new version of Chrome (about version 20) introduced a new bug rendering CSS.

Here what it's supposed to be:
[image: correct rendering]

And how new Chrome displays it:
[image: incorrect rendering]

Here is the code (jquery-ui):

```
<a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w left" style="
"></span>Up</a>
```

Firefox, and previous versions of Chrome, render the code correctly.

I'm aware we cannot fix this bug, but is there a way to workaround it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replace `span` with `img`.

Comment: And please let us know solutions you tried.

Comment: @DCoder: I can't really create a fiddle since there's jqueryui involved. However you can see a real life example here: http://webinar.videodidacte.fr/afitch2011.html (look on the top right)

Comment: @DotNETNinja: I tried swapping the <span> for a <img> and it's the same.

Comment: I suppose `white-space:nowrap;` doesn't help?

Comment: What code is adding the jQueryUI classes to the `<span></span>`. All I can see in the source is `<span></span>Up`, whereas inspecting the Chrome element I am seeing the expected `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturnthick-1-w left"></span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked in IE9 and there is no wrapping as expected.

From <s>some</s> a lot of digging, I think it's a Chrome 21 bug, which although seems to be fixed I am still seeing similar problems in Chrome 24.

I checked your site on [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/http://webinar.videodidacte.fr/afitch2011.html) and see the breakage seems to be between Chrome 20.0.1132.57 [Chrome 20.0.1132.57 http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/fa/fac627c3240bca39ef441ef4a5379a41.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/fa/fac627c3240bca39ef441ef4a5379a41.png) and Chrome 21.0.1180.89 [Chrome 21.0.1180.89 http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/25/256df60f8f44dfa2fda3b7270094aa96.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/original/25/256df60f8f44dfa2fda3b7270094aa96.png)

There seems to be [quite a few](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chrome%2021%20rendering%20problems) (font) rendering problems with Chrome 21, for example on the [release blog post](http://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=8982037438137564684&postID=4921361292784448327) and I found a relevant WebKit bug [Float imprecision causes incorrect wrapping in LineLayout with subpixel layout](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92778) which was *apparently* fixed in Chrome 22. However Chrome bugs reporting bad wrapping are still [being reported](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=141548) and in the case of the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbsto/NnsgG/) from that last bug, it is still broken for me in Chrome 24 and not in IE9

One part stood out in the WebKit bug:

> effectively means that the value can be off by almost 1

which I interpreted as "width could be off by almost 1px" and in fact changing the width of your *Up* anchor tag from the calculated `width:31px` to hard-coded `width:32px` corrects the issue for that menu item. However this is not a general fix, so I suggest removing the factor that is causing the bug, namely the *float* property.

Changing your `.left` class to from `{ float:left }` to:

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

looks like it fixes the issue. However, this will not work "as-is" for IE 6 or 7 visitors (see http://caniuse.com/#search=inline-block). There are ways around this if you need the site to behave identically on those old browsers - [How to fix display:inline-block on IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754469/how-to-fix-displayinline-block-on-ie6)

Lastly, if this approach is acceptable, I would rename the CSS `.left` rule to something more representative of where the properties are applied for example `.nav-icon` :-)

Comment: Wow very cool! That works, too bad for IE users, they should move to the 21th century ;) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the `<a>` tag.

Comment: It works, partially: the icon goes back to the correct position, but a longer menu wouldn't wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick would be to swap `<a>` for `<div>`, but as the rendering is done by jquery-ui, it might be tricky. I'll try to find a way and I'll post it here.