# How to make more divs after each other non-wrapping, but the entire list wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I have divs after each other that look like this.

```
<div class="tag">one tag</div>
<div class="tag">second tag</div>
<div class="tag">third tag</div>
...50 more of them....


(in CSS)

.tag {
    display:inline
}
```

I found out that I have too many of them and they start breaking in the middle, and I don't want that.

However, when I set the nowrap like this

```
.tag {
    display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

all of them are on one line, making more than 100% of the window. I don't want that.

What I want: if there are too many of these divs on one line, the list of the divs can break, but the divs themselves don't. I just don't want to break the divs in the middle.

I hope I tell it clearly enough.

Comment: Possibly `display:inline-block`. Could you create a demo of the problem, maybe on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Well I have two answers already. I didnt know jsfiddle, thanks!

Comment: There is [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) also (and probably more). Nice tools for making demos :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want them to lay side to side, and then break to a new line when the row is full, but not in the middle of a div.

All you need is

```
.tag {
    float: left;
}
```

See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sd8xf/) for demo.

You can also add `padding-left: 5px;` if you want some space between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
.tag {
    display:inline;
    white-space:nowrap;
    float:left;
}
```

That worked. (and adding "clearing" empty div with clear:both under that.)

Comment: If you use `inline-block` you will not need to clear anything

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers you need/want to support, you may find using

```
.tag {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

a better solution. Since it is a `<div>` that you want to apply this to, the style will **not work** out of the box for IE5-7 - see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03. There are workarounds of course - [How to fix display:inline-block on IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754469/how-to-fix-displayinline-block-on-ie6) - if you want to use it with those browsers.

The benefit of `inline-block` is that you do not need to `clear` the floated content and also that your elements are not rendered *out of normal flow*. I try to avoid floating elements where possible as in my experience it has caused layout problems.

However, there are a couple of potential catches with this approach. One of which I have already addressed, by adding a `vertical-align:top` rule. See a previous answer for why this happens - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950536/637889

The other is due to *potentially* unwanted white-space between the `inline-block` elements. See http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ for some clever ways around this.