# Work out the last div in row from a collection of floated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent element containing multiple child elements.

These child elements are floated, and could be different widths and heights to one another. I do not know before hand how many elements there are or their dimensions.

Visually I want them to appear as rows within the parent container. However, as they are floated and are varying widths/heights how can I make sure that the relevant elements are cleared?

If I use jQuery to work out the last elements on each row I can insert a clearing div after each one in order to get the visual rows that I need.

**How can work out the last element of each row?**

**As an example of the problem and the ideal solution:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4CFt/3/)

However I don't have the luxury of inserting that `<div class="clear"></div>` in the source mark up so how can I calculate that last div in row and insert it dynamically?

**N.b.** I do not want to set any min heights on the childElements.

Comment: You can calculate the right position of each element very easily, if that will help.

Comment: you could use something like [mansonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope.js](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the BEST solution, but one that works for what you have.

I have put together a little bit of jQuery that just checks to make sure the width of the childElements does not exceed that of the parent element.

```
$(function(){

    var maxWidth = $('.parentElement').outerWidth();
    var rollingWidth = 0;

    $('.childElement').each(function(index, item){

        // updated to cache jQuery item.
        var $item = $(item);

        rollingWidth += $item.outerWidth();

        if( rollingWidth > maxWidth){
            $item.css('clear','left');
            rollingWidth = $item.outerWidth();
        }

    });

});
```

Check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4CFt/4/)

Comment: that's a nice solution and could work for my specific needs. I'll wait a little bit for possible other answers before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the child elements using `inline-block` instead of floating them. You will have to get rid of the annoying space though, I used negative margins here:

```
display:inline-block;
margin:0 -4px 1px 0;
vertical-align: top;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4CFt/8/

Comment: where does that space come from?

Comment: Basically from spaces in the markup. Theres a pretty good walkthrough here presenting different ways of getting rid of it: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I would definitely prefer a css solution to this. can you think of any problems I may encounter by using inline-block over float.. big question I know but as a starter what can I expect?

Comment: I’d say inline-box (or flexbox) is the most natural way of presenting the layout you are describing, floats is a legacy technique that was meant to be used for images inside articles. But it’s a matter of preference. Box layouts does have some browser issues, but they are quite easily dealt with.

Comment: I am always wary of `inline-block` due to older browsers not supporting it.

Comment: @TimBJames I hear you, but usually, adding `*display:inline;zoom:1;` is enough for IE6+7, because `display:inline` works the same in those browsers (they shrinkwrap). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754469/how-to-fix-displayinline-block-on-ie6

Comment: Yeah good solution. I need to start using inline-block more these days because I have pretty much abandoned support for the older browsers.

Comment: @David i'm using this solution. although it didn't answer the specific question I asked it was still really helpful, cheers