# Not all of my CSS is working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu, nav

I have been working on a webpage for my school and the code I have written is not working. Please keep in mind I'm working on IE 6/7 since they are older school computers.

The biggest problems which I am facing in IE is that the page is not sizing correctly, but it is in Chrome. Also the CSS nav menu is not droping down in IE.

HTML:

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-size: 100%;
}
a {
    color: #333;
}
.container {
    background-color: #767070;
    width: 75%;
    height: 97%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 600px;
    border-style: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 3px #888888;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 97% !important;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #767070;
    background-size: cover;
}
.header h1 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 55px;
    top: 25px;
}
#nav {
    width: 98.8%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 6px 0;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    line-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #e7e5e5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav a: hover {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: #ddd;
    color: #666;
}
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #666;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    color: black!important;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 98.5%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #b4b4b4;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
}
#usualp {
    margin: 5px;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-indent: 50px;
}
p {
    margin: 5px;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
#fullercoursesheadings {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some / relevant HTML too? :)

Comment: You need to specify exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: IE6 doesn't support `min-width/height` and IE6-7 lacks `display: inline-block`.

Comment: `inline-block` isn't supported in IE6/7, so that's probably causing you your main problems. [CHECK HERE](http://www.caniuse.com) for browser support

Comment: Then How can I get the same effect?

Comment: Your school really needs to update their computers

Comment: I don't think ie6 supports li:hover either - I think that's only later browsers that allowed elements other than anchors to use that - that's why you had things like suckerfish js menus

Comment: So does anyone have an actual fix to my code above. I tried putting a pic but it won't let me. I understand things like the box shadow won't work on older versions of IE, but I don't know how to fix the sizing and the dropdown menu.

Comment: Try adding this doctype declaration: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> That may fix the nav menu and some of the other issues.

Comment: Thank you sean, that fixed the nav part of it, but anyone know about the sizing? It will expand if the text is longer than the page, but if the text isn't it shortens.

Answer (score 1):

I think old IE doesn't support **inline-block**
[How to fix display:inline-block on IE6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754469/how-to-fix-displayinline-block-on-ie6)